# How to kill a timer on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, timer, dialog

In one Activity I have 60s countdown timer which opens a dialog with information. I made it like fake session. How to stop timer , i passing before ends time to next Activity on got error about dialog.

I get the following error:

> 07-31 01:12:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1623):
>   android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window --
>   token android.os.BinderProxy@41175260 is not valid; is your activity
>   running?

Comment: Post your code, we all speak Android Java.

Comment: Read the documentation, this has information about the APIs.

Comment: What is the code you have and what is the error you get?

Comment: 07-31 01:12:22.199: E/AndroidRuntime(1623): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@41175260 is not valid; is your activity running?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) then there's [cancel()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html#cancel%28%29) method

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are opening a dialog in the Activity which is no longer exist.